# Hacked? How does appending a filename allow access to data on site... see example

Tags: security, hacking

Visiting all of the following sends you to the login screen:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/configuration.php
http://mysite.com/admin/login.php
```

However if you visit (note the last two portions of the url string are both .php):

```
http://mysite.com/admin/configuration.php/login.php
```

You can see the configuration screen and all of its data!

Further, if you append some GET variables you can even get editable fields:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/configuration.php/login.php?cID=1&action=edit
```

What is going on here?

I should note that this is on site using an absolutely horrible shopping cart called oscommerce. The code is a nightmare to deal with but I am stuck with it for now.

---

### EDIT

A fix based on vstm's excellent and accurate comment below:

This would go just before the check to see if `$current_page != FILENAME_LOGIN` (around lines 141-143 in /admin/includes/application_top.php). Mind you this is just an emergency patch as the real solution is to never use oscommerce as it is about as secure as a hooker's belt.

```
//$current_page = basename($PHP_SELF); //this is the default
$current_page = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); //change that default to this

if ( ($current_page == FILENAME_LOGIN) && !tep_session_is_registered('redirect_origin') ) {
      $current_page = FILENAME_DEFAULT;
      $HTTP_GET_VARS = array();
    }
```

If anyone tries this don't forget that the `redirect_origin` session var might already be set so this will appear to not work. Just unset it and try again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the includes/application_top which gets included by all the scripts in `/admin` you'll find this little gem (I have thrown some uninteresting parts out):

```
// redirect to login page if administrator is not yet logged in
if (!tep_session_is_registered('admin')) {
    $redirect = false;

    $current_page = basename($PHP_SELF);

    if ($current_page != FILENAME_LOGIN) {
        // session stuf blabla
        $redirect = true;
    }

    if ($redirect == true) {
        tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_LOGIN));
    }

    unset($redirect);
}
```

This code gets only executed when you are not logged in. What it basically does is check if the `basename` of `$PHP_SELF` is login.php. If it is login.php then it proceeds rendering the page, otherwise you will be redirected.

If you make this request:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/configuration.php/login.php
```

Then the PHP_SELF will be

```
/admin/configuration.php/login.php
```

And `basename($PHP_SELF)` will of course be `login.php` thus the rendering continues and no redirect is executed. But it is of course not `login.php` which gets rendered but `configuration.php`. The rest of the URL "/login.php" is "ignored" and just supplied to PHP in $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].

Edit: I like to add that this "bug" affects only oscommerce or any other software that uses a solution like that to "secure" the administration login (I think there aren't that many which suffer from this). It is not a bug which affects all PHP-software.

Comment: Nice example, +1.

Comment: Yep. I just found this myself. My fix is up as an edit to my original comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you could also replace `$PHP_SELF` with `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` this should also do the trick, since it contains the path of the real php file which is actually executed (in your example it would be `/filesystem/path/to/your/admin/configuration.php`).

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a vulnerability in the `configuration.php` file - the 'fake directory' thing with a php file as part of the path is an intentional feature and something that you'll see often - how the stuff after the slash is handled is up to the php file in the path. (mediawiki comes to mind as a good example)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this on a windows box, to use a double url as indicated - it says page not found. But the server is set not to allow directory transversals and OSCommerce is set to check user agent and prevent spider sessions as well as use a sessions directory - possibly this is why it is secure and does not allow appending a url. Additionally, the server treats the /login.php as part of the first filename, does not allow driectory transversals and does not allow dot in a filename - hence it refuses the url entirely. Therfore secure because the server is secure regardless of what the catalog software tries to do.